# App icon isnt showing on notification bar

Tags: flutter, notifications

So i tried this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/location) to get the geolocation from user in the background. Everything works except the notification. The app icon isnt showing, how can i fix this issue?

this is the code that i use

```
class BackgroundLocation {
  final bool backgroundMode;
  final location = Location();

  BackgroundLocation({required this.backgroundMode}) {
    initLocation();
  }

  initLocation() {
    // Enable Background Mode
    location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: backgroundMode);

    // Change Notification Option
    location.changeNotificationOptions(
      title: 'Plowas Sedang Berjalan Di Latar Belakang',
      color: const Color(0xFF4B7EFF)
    );
  }

  Future<LocationData> getLocation() async {
    return await location.getLocation();
  }

}
```

[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uukt6.jpg)

Comment: Hi Melvin, please add more information, such as the code you use to generate the notification, or which dependency you are using for this, maybe some configuration missing?

Comment: @George Oops, my apologies. Added the code and for the dependencies i use this [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the API reference of the `location` library you are using, we can find the method you use to set the notification. [Check the docs here](https://pub.dev/documentation/location/latest/location/Location/changeNotificationOptions.html).

You need to provide the iconName, as per the documentation:

> searches for a drawable resource with the given `iconName`. If no matching resource is found, no icon is shown.

Since it says "drawable", I would say you need to use the drawable folder on the android folder only, not the assets.